# Pass list values into class with a loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, oop, typeerror

I am trying to pass multiple input entries i as arguments into class Student(). After the last iteration (m), I get a type error. I already tried a for-loop as well, but it didn't work either. Thanks for your help!

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, d, a, b, c):
        self.d = d
        self.a = a #name
        self.b = b #roll
        self.c = c #percentage
        return#

    def uid(self):
        print('UID:', self.d)

    def name(self):
        print('Name:', self.a)

    def roll(self):
        print('Roll:', self.b)

    def perc(self):
        print('Perc:', self.c)


#THIS IS WHAT YOUR INPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:        
#Peter 405 100

m = input('how many entries? ')
n = 0

while n < int(m):
    i = input()
    j = i.split()
    o = Student(n,*j)
    o.uid(), o.name(), o.roll(), o.perc()
    n+=1    

Student()
```

Comment: what last line supposed to do?

Comment: also using single-character names is a bad way to go

Comment: the last line is supposed to create the type error :) - thanks for your input! @AzatIbrakov

Comment: you should not use `while` when your loop-lenth is fixed; use a `for`-loop instead

Comment: @MarcelZoll - thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The last line - Student() creates an instance of the class without providing any arguments. Hence, Python raises a type error.

Deleting this line (or entering the arguments) will fix the problem.

Comment: this should be a comment, doesn't look like an analysis of what happened and how it can be fixed

Comment: @AzatIbrakov - ok like this?

Comment: the problem here is why there was this line at the beginning? what does it suppose to mean?